# Innodb foreign key constraints

Tags: innodb

I am trying to change the type in two tables of an `innoDB`. The problem is that the values are a key and a foreign key. When I try to make the change I get the following error

```
#1025 error on rename
```

Do I need to drop the foreign keys and then make the changes and then reapply the foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

Since u can use the name to drop the foreign key first and the column then:

```
ALTER TABLE categories DROP FOREIGN KEY categories_ibfk_1;
ALTER TABLE categories DROP COLUMN assets_id;
```

To find out which table caused the error you can run

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

and then look at the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" section.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to drop the foreign key. Try `SHOW INNODB STATUS` to see if there's a more elaborated explanation of what's going on.